# Joomla Trigger a Event after Article is Saved

Tags: joomla

I want to create a simple event after a article is posted, e.q when admin post a article with category sale I want to fire a event and send SMS to subscribed users.

Is it possible

Regards

Comment: yes, it is possible. Have you tried anything of your own yet? Please do so and ask your question again when you run into a specific coding related problem

Comment: Hi Lodder, Plz share code, I am very new to joomla. plz guide

Comment: I have no specific code that I have used before as I have never needed to do this, nor am I going to write it all for you. Even if you are new to something, we expect you to try something of your own before asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Its [sample content plugin](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-plugin-development-tutorial) for Joomla,

In this plugin I used `onContentPrepare()` instead of this you have to use [onContentAfterSave](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/Content#onContentAfterSave).

Hope its helps..